# cannot resolve symbol

Tags: asp.net

i have made a simple table (lets call it **volunteers**), but when i want to call it in my **code behind** Visual studio can not recognize it. The error is **cannot resolve symbol 'volunteers'**.

here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="root_VerifyUsers.aspx.cs" 
     MasterPageFile="~/Root.Master" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

               <p>
                   <asp:Table runat="server" ID="volunteers" ForeColor="Green" Width="100%" Height="85%"  BorderColor="Red"></asp:Table>

                   <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="NationalId" runat="server">National Id</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                   <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="Email" runat="server">Email</asp:TableHeaderCell>
               </p>

</asp:Content>
```

that is behind code:

```
public partial class RootVerifyUsers : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        TableCell fname = new TableCell();

        TableCell NationalId=new TableCell();
        tr.Cells.Add(NationalId);
        volunteers.Rows.add(tr);

    }
```

}

Comment: Cannot resolve what symbol? That's not the whole error. Why wouldn't you post the whole error? Trying to make it a challenge?

Comment: Sorry for careless, but i am new in asp and not going to make challenge.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Any plug ins you are using by chance ??

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved by adding this attribute

```
Inherits="Library.Account.RootVerifyUsers"
```

Thanks everyone for helping

Answer (score 0):

You have `asp:TableHeaderCell` with an id of `NationalId` and a local variable called `NationalId`:

```
TableCell NationalId=new TableCell();
```

That isn't going to work... Change one of them to start with..

Also, have a look at the examples on [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.aspx), to correctly structure your `<asp:Table...`

Comment: What did you change NationalId to, and what is the error message?

Comment: I would also put the tableheadercells inside the table.

Answer (score 0):

Your TableHeaderCell should be inside Table tag

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="volunteers" ForeColor="Green" Width="100%" Height="85%"  BorderColor="Red">

               <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="NationalId" runat="server">National Id</asp:TableHeaderCell>
               <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="Email" runat="server">Email</asp:TableHeaderCell>
</asp:Table>
```