# Upload file on Google drive

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to upload an image on google drive using webapi. I copied the following chunk from Google drive doc but I am getting an error.
Here is the code:

```
            var clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleDriveClientSecret"];
            var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret },
            scopes, Environment.UserName, CancellationToken.None).Result;
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = credential });

            var folderId = "0B2bBiMQICgHCMlp6OUxuSHNaZFU";
            var fileMetadata = new File()
            {
                Name = "photo.jpg",
                Parents = new List<string>
    {
        folderId
    }
            };
            FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
            using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("files/photo.jpg",
                System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {

                request = service.Files.Create(
                    fileMetadata, stream, "image/jpeg");
                request.Fields = "id";
                request.Upload();
            }
            var file = request.ResponseBody;
```

Now I am getting 2 errors in this code. First "Cannot resolve symbol Upload" at request.Upload() and second "Cannot resolve symbol ResponseBody" at request.ResponseBody

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869645/cannot-resolve-symbol). The adding the attribute `Inherits="Library.Account.RootVerifyUsers"`. Based from this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33131383/5832311), Visual Studio can often get confused about things like this. It is recommended to close Visual Studio and reopen it. Also, closing all open instances of VS may be required.